# Firefox developer group styles in computed view

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, computed-style

Is it possible to group the styles shown in the "Computed" tab in Firefox Developer as formerly shown in Firebug? There the styles were grouped in text-styles, background-styles and so on which could be collapsed and this was much more clearly arranged and easier to access than the alphabetic order which Firefox Developer shows. To find a specific style you have to filter (and thus know the name) or to tab through all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such option yet. There is already a [request to add this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977128), though.